# Флешка в устройствах

Tags: usb

Как перепаять контакты? Вместо микро сд поставить выход юсб? Для смены флешки. Какие контакты нужно перепаевать?

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что точно так же, как и PS/2 на USB. Т.е. никак.

Comment: Без контроллера дополнительного - никак.

Comment: Считайте коментарий @Алексей Сонькин ответом

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вопрос не имеет смысла без предварительного сравнения электрической схемы и протоколов обмена данными у MicroSD и USB, а так же описания контактов.
Навскидку могу предположить, что никак не перепаять - это разные девайсы с разными правилами функционирования.

Comment: Без всяких скидок скажу, что они точно разные=) Но при очень-очень большом желании "согласоватор" в любую сторону запрограммировать и запаять, думаю, вполне возможно.

Answer (score 1):

Перепаять - точно, никак! 
Часто MicroSD продаются в комплекте с таким контроллером (переходником). Его размер - 30Х15Х1 мм, цена флешки  с переходником больше на 20 - 50 руб.